# Fully joint connected multibody system?

Tags: drake

I'm currently creating a system of spheres which can actuate to push each other away. There are center bodies (teal) at each corner which are connected to connecting bodies (yellow) via `PrismaticJoint` which are connected in the same way to the next corner.

When creating a one dimensional system of spheres, for example, a 1x1x4 system, I run into no errors and the system behaves as expected.

In trying to create a system of eight spheres in a 2x2x2 orientation, I'm running into mobilization errors.
Here is what the system looks like:

[image: 2x2x2 system, where teal spheres are centers and yellow spheres are connecting bodies]

And the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  This mobilizer is creating a closed loop since the outboard body already has an inboard mobilizer connected to it. If a physical loop is really needed, consider using a constraint instead.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I understand that the error comes for joints sharing child or outward bodies, like in the case for two sides of the cube actuating one corner. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to pivot using constraints successfully. How can I better define this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to address this is to use a Drake [bushing element](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_linear_bushing_roll_pitch_yaw.html) (essentially a stiff spring and damper) to emulate a "weld" constraint. There is a nice example of this approach in Drake -- see [examples/multibody/four_bar](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/multibody/four_bar).

The general idea is to break topological loops by sawing through one or more bodies, then welding them back together with a bushing (which does not count as a topological loop).

Comment: This may have been exactly what I was looking for - as I wanted a bit of compliance between these body connections anyway! I'll see how this goes.

Comment: I attempted this with a single joint connection in the orientation I had but am running into some strange errors. It attempt to connect connectors from two different spheres on the Z axis, which should be welded together. Setting k_z above ~210 causes the visualizer to fail, or for the bodies involved to disappear. With d_z there is a similar limit. There are also other unexplained behaviors such as the joints seeming to ignore joint limits, etc.

Comment: I wonder if you are running into stability problems? See if it works at a smaller step size. If you are doing continuous integration you could try an implicit integrator also. If you aren't already, I would suggest making a very small, simple system for debugging and then building up to the full system after the small one is working satisfactorily.

Comment: I found constants which worked for my system and now it behaves much better! Yes, I initially tested only 'welding' two bodies, and then expanded to the rest. Check it out: https://i.imgur.com/ewKbyX8.png Unfortunately, I still haven't solved my joint limits problem though, and put it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788760/prismaticjoint-limits-not-enforced