# PrismaticJoint limits not enforced

Tags: drake

I'm creating a system of bodies with radially expanding bodies connected with PrismaticJoints, and finding that, although I initialized each joint with joint position limits, the joints pass these limits due to external forces like gravity easily. Here is a plot showing some joints' translations over time to show how they pass the lower and upper limits at 3.5 and 4.2:
[image]

What am I missing? My call to create the joints looks like this:

```
const multibody::Joint<double>& joint = plant_->AddJoint<drake::multibody::PrismaticJoint>(
        shpere_name + "_joint",
        center_body, std::nullopt,
        connect_body, std::nullopt,
        unitVlist()[j], r_low, r_upp, 0);
```

where

- *_body are bodies,
- unitVlist() returns a list of unit vectors to pull from,
- r_low and r_upp are doubles corresponding to the lower and upper limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently joint limits in Drake are only enforced by the discrete solver, that is, what you get if you supply a time step in the MultibodyPlant constructor. Our continuous integrators don't see the limits yet. We are aware of that but I couldn't actually find a GitHub issue complaining about it -- would you mind filing one? You can do it [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues) (select "New Issue").

Comment: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13245 is this the issue? If not, I'm happy to post another issue (specifying joint limits for the **continuous** MBP?)

Comment: Also, I believe I am using the discrete solver, since I construct MBP with
`auto [plant, scene_graph] =
      multibody::AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, FLAGS_time_step);`
with time_step 3e-3

Comment: Oh okay - just changed the time_step to 3e-4 and limits were enforced.

Comment: @JoaquinGiraldo-Laguna Since it's your `time_step` affecting you, I think the most relevant issue is: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12775

Comment: Regarding the issue, #13245 is about the heuristics used by the discrete solver but doesn't note the problem with the continuous solvers not seeing the limits at all. However, I see you are using the discrete solver so no need to file an issue about the continuous one!